# How to drop columns with a particular word in DataFrame (version 0.19)?

Tags: dataframe, julia

DatFrame, as follows:

```
julia> df1
27×19 DataFrame. Omitted printing of 6 columns
│ Row │ County       │ Female (2012) │ Male (2012) │ Total (2012) │ Female (2011) │ Male (2011) │ Total (2011) │ Female (2010) │ Male (2010) │ Total (2010) │ Female (2009) │ Male (2009) │ Total (2009) │
│     │ String       │ Int64         │ Int64       │ Int64        │ Int64         │ Int64       │ Int64        │ Int64         │ Int64       │ Int64        │ Int64         │ Int64       │ Int64        │
├─────┼──────────────┼───────────────┼─────────────┼──────────────┼───────────────┼─────────────┼──────────────┼───────────────┼─────────────┼──────────────┼───────────────┼─────────────┼──────────────┤
│ 1   │ Asotin       │ 0             │ 0           │ 0            │ 0             │ 0           │ 0            │ 0             │ 0           │ 0            │ 0             │ 0           │ 0            │
│ 2   │ Benton       │ 0             │ 0           │ 0            │ 0             │ 0           │ 0            │ 0             │ 0           │ 0            │ 0             │ 0           │ 0            │
│ 3   │ Chelan       │ 0             │ 2           │ 2            │ 0             │ 0           │ 0            │ 0             │ 1           │ 1            │ 1             │ 0           │ 1            │
│ 4   │ Clallam      │ 0             │ 0           │ 0            │ 1             │ 1           │ 2            │ 0             │ 0           │ 0            │ 0             │ 0           │ 0            │
│ 5   │ Clark        │ 1             │ 3           │ 4            │ 0             │ 2           │ 2            │ 0             │ 0           │ 0            │ 0             │ 0           │ 0            │
│ 6   │ Columbia     │ 0             │ 0           │ 0            │ 0             │ 0           │ 0            │ 0             │ 1           │ 1            │ 0             │ 0           │ 0            │
│ 7   │ Cowlitz      │ 0             │ 0           │ 0            │ 0             │ 0           │ 0            │ 0             │ 1           │ 1            │ 0             │ 0           │ 0            │
│ 8   │ Douglas      │ 0             │ 1           │ 1            │ 0             │ 0           │ 0            │ 0             │ 1           │ 1            │ 0             │ 0           │ 0            │
│ 9   │ Grays Harbor │ 0             │ 3           │ 3            │ 1             │ 1           │ 2            │ 0             │ 1           │ 1            │ 0             │ 0           │ 0            │
│ 10  │ Island       │ 0             │ 2           │ 2            │ 0             │ 0           │ 0            │ 0             │ 0           │ 0            │ 0             │ 0           │ 0            │
│ 11  │ Jefferson    │ 0             │ 0           │ 0            │ 0             │ 1           │ 1            │ 0             │ 0           │ 0            │ 0             │ 0           │ 0            │
│ 12  │ King         │ 3             │ 10          │ 13           │ 4             │ 2           │ 6            │ 1             │ 2           │ 3            │ 4             │ 3           │ 7            │
│ 13  │ Kitsap       │ 0             │ 0           │ 0            │ 0             │ 0           │ 0            │ 0             │ 0           │ 0            │ 0             │ 1           │ 1            │
│ 14  │ Lewis        │ 0             │ 0           │ 0            │ 0             │ 0           │ 0            │ 0             │ 0           │ 0            │ 0             │ 0           │ 0            │
│ 15  │ Mason        │ 0             │ 1           │ 1            │ 0             │ 0           │ 0            │ 0             │ 0           │ 0            │ 0             │ 0           │ 0            │
│ 16  │ Okanogan     │ 0             │ 0           │ 0            │ 0             │ 2           │ 2            │ 0             │ 0           │ 0            │ 0             │ 0           │ 0            │
│ 17  │ Pacific      │ 0             │ 0           │ 0            │ 0             │ 0           │ 0            │ 1             │ 1           │ 2            │ 0             │ 1           │ 1            │
│ 18  │ Pierce       │ 1             │ 3           │ 4            │ 0             │ 3           │ 3            │ 0             │ 3           │ 3            │ 0             │ 3           │ 3            │
│ 19  │ Skagit       │ 0             │ 1           │ 1            │ 0             │ 1           │ 1            │ 0             │ 0           │ 0            │ 1             │ 0           │ 1            │
│ 20  │ Snohomish    │ 0             │ 1           │ 1            │ 0             │ 2           │ 2            │ 0             │ 5           │ 5            │ 0             │ 0           │ 0            │
│ 21  │ Spokane      │ 0             │ 1           │ 1            │ 0             │ 2           │ 2            │ 1             │ 1           │ 2            │ 1             │ 0           │ 1            │
│ 22  │ Stevens      │ 0             │ 1           │ 1            │ 0             │ 1           │ 1            │ 0             │ 0           │ 0            │ 0             │ 0           │ 0            │
│ 23  │ Thurston     │ 0             │ 0           │ 0            │ 0             │ 0           │ 0            │ 0             │ 0           │ 0            │ 0             │ 1           │ 1            │
│ 24  │ Walla Walla  │ 0             │ 0           │ 0            │ 0             │ 0           │ 0            │ 0             │ 0           │ 0            │ 0             │ 1           │ 1            │
│ 25  │ Whatcom      │ 0             │ 1           │ 1            │ 1             │ 1           │ 2            │ 0             │ 1           │ 1            │ 1             │ 0           │ 1            │
│ 26  │ Whitman      │ 0             │ 0           │ 0            │ 0             │ 0           │ 0            │ 0             │ 1           │ 1            │ 0             │ 0           │ 0            │
│ 27  │ Yakima       │ 0             │ 1           │ 1            │ 0             │ 3           │ 3            │ 1             │ 2           │ 3            │ 0             │ 1           │ 1            │
```

Please guide me in dropping all the columns having column names like 'Total'.

Comment: DataFrames.jl 0.19 has not been supported for a long time and is not recommended to be used. We do not backport bug fixes to this branch. Why do you have to use it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try (excludes columns with case insensitive "total" in name):

```
dfMF = select(df, Not(r"total"i))
```